# Problem HTACCESS: How to give priority absolute path?

Tags: .htaccess

We are busy with a name change for our webshop and i am working on our HTACCESS to redirect 1700 links. from those 1700 links there are 177 links that are changing in our new webshop. So they have to be in the HTACCESS. The other links keep the same and i redirect them now with a general rewriterule.

The only problem now is that he does not look well what the exact link is. For example see below my HTACCESS.

```
RewriteEngine on

# Redirect to domain with www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Same for HTTPS:
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^vloerkleden/categorie/(.*)$ https://www.new.nl/vloerkleden/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^vloerkleden/categorie/vintage-vloerkleed/(.*)$ https://www.new.nl/vloerkleden/vintage-vloerkleed/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.nl [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.new.nl/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

When i type now the following url in the browser www.old.nl/vloerkleden/catagorie/vintage-vloerkleed/ he links me to www.new.nl/vloerkleden in stead of www.new.nl/vloerkleden/vintage-vloerkleed.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in this line :

```
RewriteRule ^vloerkleden/categorie/(.*)$ https://www.new.nl/vloerkleden/ [R=301,L]
```

Nothig to present `(.*)$` in substitution `https://www.new.nl/vloerkleden/` so , it should look like this `https://www.new.nl/vloerkleden/$1` because `$1` will represent `(.*)` in pattern.

Also , you could do this with another rules and you could also sumerize your rules like this :

```
RewriteEngine on

# the folwoing rules will force every request for both old & new into https://wwww:

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off  [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?!.*www\.)(.*)$
RewriteRule .* https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^vloerkleden/categorie/(.*)$ https://www.new.nl/vloerkleden/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.nl$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^vloerkleden/categorie/vintage-vloerkleed/(.*)$ https://www.new.nl/vloerkleden/vintage-vloerkleed/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old.nl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.new.nl/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

**Note:** clear browser cache then test.